# Why startRow and endRow could be undefined when SSRM?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm struggling with wrong work of SSRM. I have set it up but each time I'm getting `startRow` and `endRow` as undefined.

So, I have that setup:

Setting up the DataSource:

```
  onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(this.createServerSideDatasource());
  };
```

DataSource:

```
  createServerSideDatasource(): IServerSideDatasource {
    return {
      getRows: (params) => {
        this.api.getTrades(params.request).subscribe({
          next: (resp) => {
            params.success({
              rowData: resp?.data ?? [],
              rowCount: resp?.totalRowCount,
            });
          },
          error: () => params.fail(),
        });
      },
    };
  }
```

Template:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  *ngIf="gridSettings.value && colDef; else loading"
  class="ag-theme-core-sdk ag-grid"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="colDef"
  [gridOptions]="gridSettings.value.gridOptions"
  [modules]="gridSettings.value.modules"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Package.json:

```
{
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "27.2.0",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "~27.2.0",
}
```

I tried to change the version of AgGrid and found that it works when 29.2.0 is used but I have dependencies which are not working with the oldest version.
Also I tried 28.2.1 but it works similar to 27.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `serverSideStoreType` with a value `partial`.

I could not find this within the documentation however, there is an article about upgrading to version 25, which describes the situation well.

https://blog.ag-grid.com/upgrading-to-ag-grid-v25-server-side-row-model/